# How can I get first 6 items after filtering with isotope.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I need to add a class for first six filtered items.

The first item I have solution for from the official documentation:

```
$($container.data('isotope').filteredItems[0].element).addClass('first');
```

How do I add that class for the next five items?

Answer (score 1):

@Desandro´s answer on Isotope repository: https://github.com/metafizzy/isotope/issues/1040

Here's one way to do it:

```
// get Isotope instance
var iso = $container.data('isotope');
// add class to first 6 elements
iso.filteredItems.forEach( function( item, i ) {
  if ( i < 6 ) {
    $( item.element ).addClass('first-6');
  }
});
```

or

```
// get array of first 6 item elements
var firstElems = iso.filteredItems.slice( 0, 6 ).map( function( item ) {
  return item.element;
});
$( firstElems ).addClass('first-6');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do the same thing in a loop:

```
if($container.data('isotope').filteredItems.length >= 6)
{
    for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
    {
       $($container.data('isotope').filteredItems[i].element).addClass('first');
    }
}
```